Please help me identify IC TP84
Please help me identify following IC. TP84



Can you measure the capsule body. Is it SOT23-5 or SOT89-5?

it is sot23-5..

@winny There is no gullwing version of SOT-89; it always has flat leads. And even the 5-lead variant has six visible leads; the center one on each side are just connected together as a heatsink pad.

@Hearth Good catch! I would have guessed on SOT23 over SOT89, but wasn’t sure. I’ll keep the gullwing in mind.

@winny You might be thinking of SC-88A, aka SOT-353, which does look just like a resized SOT-23-5. It's the 5-lead version of the better-known SC-70/SOT-323 package (it's often called "5-lead SC-70" or "SC-70-5" etc.). It's smaller than SOT-23, though, while SOT-89 is larger.

@Hearth Indeed, SC70-5 was the one I was thinking of.

Jeez. It doesn't help that it starts with "TP" because every search engine is probably going to think we're looking for a Texas Instruments device LOL...

It is a CAT4139TD 22 V High Current Boost White LED Driver from Catalyst Semiconductor.
